# RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start (dir undefined)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, production-environment

I actually want to activate delayed job on production mode. So I type in "

> RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start

"  at console and
Having the error at "

> :dir        => File.join(dir, 'tmp', 'pids'),

" that report undefined dir... search online about the original file but can't find any.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config',   'environment'))
require 'delayed/command'
Delayed::Command.new(ARGV).daemonize
daemon_options = {
  :multiple   => false,
  :dir_mode   => :normal,
  **:dir        => File.join(dir, 'tmp', 'pids'),**
  :backtrace  => true
}

Daemons.run_proc('job_runner', daemon_options) do
  if ARGV.include?('--')
    ARGV.slice! 0..ARGV.index('--')
  else
    ARGV.clear
  end

  Dir.chdir dir
  RAILS_ENV = ARGV.first || ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'
  require File.join('config', 'environment')

  Delayed::Worker.new.start
 end
```

Comment: yup... heroku, but it now clashed. =(

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `dir` with `Rails.root` (replace both occurrences).  The variable or method `dir` was never defined in the above code.  You could also define dir above `daemon_options`:

```
dir = Rails.root
daemon_options = {
  ...
```

Comment: do you replace dir that in ":dir => File.join(dir, 'tmp', 'pids')," with Rails.root or other dir?

Comment: Yes, change it to ":dir => File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp', 'pids')," and change "Dir.chdir dir" to "Dir.chdir Rails.root"

Comment: No error output after the change. Thanks. But there is also no sight of delayed_job running at the background in production mode. Do you mind tell me are there any other configurations needed to do? or how to verify it? thank you.

Comment: How did you check for the process?  Do you see a process after running `ps aux | grep -v grep | grep delayed` from the terminal?

Comment: Looking closer at the code, I think you can safely remove everything after `Delayed::Command.new(ARGV).daemonize`.  That line sets up the daemon for you, and it can be configured by adding flags to `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start`.  The flag options can be viewed by running `script/delayed_job --help`.

Comment: After I type "ps aux | grep -v grep | grep delayed" in the console, nothing happen.